# React Native index.js unable to resolve path to module '/src/App.js

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have been running the simulator successfully for some time now, however, the index.js file seems unable to resolve the path to the App.js file in the src folder.

I am getting the following error on ESLint:     Unable to resolve path to module './src/App'. (import/no-unresolved)

I am getting the following error in the ios and android simulators: 
failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?
platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(unable to resolve module `./src/App` from `Users/williamgoodhew/projects/athalens/apps/index.js`: The module `./src/App` could not be found from `./Users/williamgoodhew/projects/athalens/apps/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

*`/Users/williamgoodhew/projects/athalens/apps/src/App(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
*`/Users/williamgoodhew/projects/athalens/apps/src/App/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)` (null))

[this is the directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVyZU.png)

This is the index.js file

```js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';

console.ignoredYellowBox = [
    'Setting a timer'
];

AppRegistry.registerComponent('apps', () => App);
```

this is the App.js file

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import Router from './Router';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const config = {
      apiKey: '...........................',
      authDomain: '..........firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://...............firebaseio.com',
      projectId: '...........',
      storageBucket: '..............appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: '.................'
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hey did you find what was the issue?

Comment: `react-native start --reset-cache` on one terminal and `react-native run-android` on another terminal did the trick for me. Let me know if it works.